# sudo: command not found, despite path being set correctly

Tags: terminal, bash, sudo

Recently, I've been unable to use the sudo command in terminal. Any command I try to give it, file I try to get it to run, etc, tells me `sudo: [command or file]: command not found`. If I try to run sudo without any arguments though, it tells me the usage and what arguments I am allowed to use with sudo, so I know the system is at least *aware* of sudo — it's just broken.

I've followed the answers to all the other questions i've seen with a similar issue, but none of them have helped.

echo $PATH gives me `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`, so that's all set properly

I don't believe .bash_profile is in use (I'm on Apple silicon which means it uses .zprofile instead, from what I understand?), but I set the PATH there just in case. .zprofile had some changes to it from installing python, but I commented those out and set the PATH anyway just to be safe. Still nothing.

```
# The original version is saved in .zprofile.pysave
#PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin:${PATH}"
#export PATH
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
export PATH
```

What's going on?

Comment: Is the command actually in any of those paths?  What happens if you use the full path?

Comment: Yes, sudo is present in usr/bin. Using the full path still gives the same command not found error

Comment: Seems like the full path is not correct - are spaces or other characters special to the shell properly escaped?

Comment: I would say test with something simple like `sudo ls` before making the claim that `sudo` might be broken.

Comment: The error isn't saying that `sudo` isn't found. It says that the command you're trying to run with it isn't found.

Comment: What if you do `sudo /bin/ls`?

Comment: Ah, okay, yeah, `sudo ls` and `sudo /bin/ls` both work. So sudo isn't broken. But the command was just `sudo` followed by the path to a .command file I dragged in, so I'm not sure why it would not be able to be found

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sudo foo
sudo: foo: command not found
```

indicates that `sudo` couldn‘t access the command you want to run. Typical reasons for this are

- the command (binary) does not exist,
- the command is not in `$PATH`,
- `root` (or whatever user you `sudo` to) doesn't have access to the command file (needs to have `o+x` rights on all directories in the path, and `o+rx` on the command file itself).

Comment: Ah! Seems to be a permissions thing. `chmod 755 [file]` fixed it. But the file was just in my documents... why would permissions be restrictive there? Is there a way to get around this so I dont have to chmod every file and folder needed by the .command file?

Comment: @GtwoK why do you need sudo at all in that case?

Comment: And if you did run it with `sudo` and it ended up creating new files in your home directory, those too will now be owned by `root` and you will be unable to do anything with them. Stop using `sudo` needlessly.

Comment: If the file was not executable at all, that would explain why it could not be found. Even `sudo` will not be able to execute things which are not executable (at least not easily).